# A phone number from a large list of phone numbers is a pre-number for another phone number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Example_List=[112,34533344,11234543,98]
```

In the above list, we can see that `112` is a pre-number of `11234543`. How can I check this in python? I think `re.match` or `re.search` are one of the solutions ?

Comment: Why not `'11234543'.startswith('112')`?

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: Ya thanks but this list is a dynamic list means a user can enter lots of phone numbers and a list will be created like: When we run the program it ask for the phone numbers, num1, num2, num3, ... and resulted list will be [112,11234,766566], it is an integer list not the string one.

Comment: do you want to get a list of numbers that starts with at least one number from the list, or with a specific number?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your numbers into strings and then sort them.
Afterwards if one number is a pre-number all numbers that start with it will follow and once a number does not start with it anymore you found all.

```
Example_List=[112,34533344,11234543,98]
list_s = sorted(str(i) for i in Example_List)

result = []
for i in range(len(list_s)):
    k=i+1
    while k<len(list_s) and list_s[k].startswith(list_s[i]):
        result.append((list_s[i],list_s[k]))
        k += 1

print(result)
```

Comment: I think there should be some mechanism to thank you via stack over flow. Thanks a lot for all to all.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help, accepting the answer is usually sufficient. ;)
This will also show others that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all numbers, starting with any number from your list you could do something like this:

```
#Converte your list of ints to list of strings
tmp = map(lambda x : str(x),l)
#Use a set so you duplicate entries are eliminated
result = set()
for x in tmp:
    #Insert all numbers starting with the current one
    result.update([y for y in filter(lambda z : z.startswith(x) and z != x, l)])
#Convert your set of ints to a list of strings
result = list(map(int, result))
```

Answer (score 0):

A single list comprehension will return all numbers in your list (as integers) which start with a specified "pre-number":

```
In [1]: Example_List=[112,34533344,11234543,98]
In [2]: [num for num in Example_List if str(num).startswith('112')]
Out[2]: [112, 11234543]
```

If your pre-number is always the first entry in your list but may be different for different lists then you can still do it in one line, but it's a little longer:

```
In [3]: [num for num in Example_List[1:] if str(num).startswith(str(Example_List[0]))]
Out[3]: [11234543]
```